# What would you see at the focal point of a perfect magnifying glass?

Tags: visible-light, refraction

What image would appear on a perfect magnifying glass in perfect vacuum with an object at exactly the distance of the focal point?

Comment: In the context of the various types of [aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_aberration), how are you defining "perfect"?

Answer (score 2):

You would not get any real picture, just parallel light from every point of you object.

Answer (score 0):

I like to look at it in terms of *paraxial Fourier Optics*:
The object at the focal point distance $f$ will create an outgoing spherical wave:

$w(t,f)=\frac{w_o}{f}\cdot e^{\frac{ikf}{cos\ \theta }} \cdot e^{-\omega \cdot t}$,

where $w_0$ is the amplitude, $k$ is the wavenumber, $\theta$ is the angle between the object and the axis of rotation of the lens, and $\omega$ is the angular frequency.

To compute the image you would see *on the lens*, you have to compute the intensity of the spherical wave for every on the lens by squaring its amplitude.